# Книги по изучению MySQL, XML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, книги

Доброго времени суток.

Такой вопрос мучает меня с самого утра: я хочу знать MySQL, XML и JavaScript, но помимо моего безудержного желания нужен материал, который поможет мне в решении моей безграмотности. Я совершенно точно знаю, что владею PHP и ... все.

Посоветуйте какие-нибудь книги, которые бы "разжевывали" всю содержимую информацию до мелочей, а то я "не бум-бум" в этих делах совсем.

Answer (score 8):

- Бер Бибо, Иегуда Кац - jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript
- Дронов.В.-.HTML.5.CSS.3.и.Web 2.0.Разработка.современных.Web-сайтов.БХВ-Петербург.2011
- Стоян Стефанов - JavaScript. Шаблоны (O'REILLY) - 2011.DjVu
- Дэвид Флэнаган JavaScript. Подробное руководство,5е издание
- Бестселлеры O'Reily - Никсон Р. - Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript
- Библиотека программиста - Гольцман В.И. - MySQL 5.0

Comment: Спасибо за список стоящих внимания книг, крайне вам благодарен)))

Answer (score 5):

Из описаных **AndereyMaybe** читал все кроме книги по MySQL...
Так вот как по мне о jquery И читать нечего... Открыл доку, пару строк кода - profit...
Для себя читал, откровенно говоря практически ничего толкового(опять таки - для себя)ненашел
Для начинающего очень хорошая книга Никсона, ну просто отличная, очень коротко и вменяемо расписано...
Дронов вообще не понравился, прочитал чисто абыб прочитать :)
А вот Дэвид Флэнаган это вообще то что нужно, с него надо начинать изучение javascript'a а не сразу в jquery лезть как делает абсолютное большинство, а потом появляются вопросы типа почему у меня не работает, а как сделать тото, ого, та не тут нету jquery, я так не шарю :D

Comment: Спасибо за советы)))